# Do Source Terms Commute with Propagator terms?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, propagator

[image]

Do source terms, $J$, commute with Feynman propagators, $\Delta$?

I.e. will the two terms in the image above be equivalent?

Comment: Both the source $J(x)$ and the propagator $\Delta(x,y)$ are just scalars in a scalar theory. They are not matrices so they do commute. Moreover notice that $\Delta(x,y)=\Delta(y,x)$. This should be enough for you to combine the two terms.

Comment: Thank you, Gold. In a non-scalar theory, QED for example, will the two terms not commute as they will contain matrix terms?

Comment: In QED the source becomes a vector $J^\mu(x)$ and the propagator becomes a tensor $\Delta_{\mu\nu}(x,y)$. However, since the propagator is $$\Delta_{\mu\nu}(x,y)\propto \langle \Omega | T\{A_\mu(x)A_\nu(y)\}|\Omega\rangle$$ it has the symmetry property $\Delta_{\mu\nu}(x,y)=\Delta_{\nu\mu}(y,x)$. Writing the analogue of what you have in coordinates and bearing what I said in mind the terms combine as well.